# SVG.js rotation animation does not work after move animation

Tags: svg.js

I use SVG.js. Here is my example:

```
var draw = SVG("svg");
var rect = draw.rect(100,100);

rect.animate(1000).move(100,100);
rect.animate(1000).rotate(50);
```

In second animation rectangular rotates around the initial center of the figure (50,50) but not around the new center after the first animation (150,150). Am I wrong in understanding these methods or is it a bug?

Comment: Just pass in a center: `rect.animate(1000).rotate(50, 150, 150);`

Comment: That's not a solution, because I don't want to control the center of the figure during multiple animations. I expected svg.js would do it for me. But it doesn't.

Comment: That's why it's a comment